# ASP relative paths to root in nested subfolders

Tags: asp-classic

I'm using ASP scripts in a virtual directory instead of a top (root) level application and i've had to write little scripts to give each page the proper path to CSS and other include files that exist right off of root. So something two levels deep would have to be at "....\"

This messes with my included header and footer templates.

Is there an easier way to manage the relative paths for nested subfolders that include headings?

Using Win2k3 Server with IIS6 ASP 3.5 32-bit running in 64-bit process

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a standard include file that you include on every page you can do something similar to what we did wWhen I worked at [webfodder](http://www.webfodder.com).

Every page included a file we called info.asp. Inside info.asp we Dim'd and set all the global variables we needed for the website. We Dim'd a variable we called strRelativePath and set it to an empty string inside info.asp.

Then on each page before we called the CSS, Header, and Footer includes (which were also xxxx.asp files) we set the strRelativePath appropriately.

strRelativePath = "..\"
strRelativePath = "..\..\"

We would then make sure all the references to images and whatever used the strRelativePath variable. For example:

<img src="<%=strRelativePath%>images\myimage.jpg">

**Edit: Upon OP's Request - Added Contents of info.asp file**
`<%
Option Explicit
Response.Buffer = true
Response.charset="ISO-8859-1"`

'==============================================================
'=== Declarations
'==============================================================
Dim strBodyTag
Dim strRelativePath
Dim strFqurl
Dim strSFqurl
Dim strReferer
Dim strServerName
Dim strMailServer
Dim strWebDSN

'==============================================================
'=== Initilization
'==============================================================
strBodyTag            = "bgcolor='#FFFFFF' topmargin='4' leftmargin='4' rightmargin='4' bottommargin='4' marginheight='0' marginwidth='0'"
strRelativePath     = ""
strReferer            = trim(lcase(Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_REFERER")))
strServerName       = lcase(Request.ServerVariables("SERVER_NAME"))
strMailServer     = "localhost" 'DO NOT CHANGE FROM "localhost"

Select Case strServerName
    Case "dev"
        strFqurl  = "http://dev/websitegoeshere/" 'INCLUDE TRAILING SLASH
        strSFqurl = "https://dev/websitegoeshere/" 'INCLUDE TRAILING SLASH
    strWebDSN = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;server=DEV\SQLEXPRESS;uid=DBUserId;pwd=DBPassword;database=DBName"
    Case Else 'PRODUCTION
        strFqurl  = "http://www.websitegoeshere.com/"   'INCLUDE TRAILING SLASH
        strSFqurl = "https://www./websitegoeshere.com/" 'INCLUDE TRAILING SLASH
    strWebDSN = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;server=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx;uid=DBUserId;pwd=DBPassword;database=DBName"
    'Note:  xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx = IP Address for Database
End Select

'==============================================================
'=== Assigns a name to each page to determin title, etc.
'==============================================================
Dim strScriptName
Dim strPageTitle
Dim strMetaDescription
Dim strMetaKeyWords
Dim strHeaderText

strScriptName      = Request.ServerVariables("Script_Name")
strScriptName      = LCase(Mid(strScriptName,InStrRev(strScriptName,"/")+1))
strPageTitle           = "Default Page Title Goes Here"
strMetaDescription = "Default Meta Description Goes Here"
strMetaKeyWords    = "Default Keywords Go Here"
strHeaderText      = "Default Header Text Goes Here"

%>

Comment: Just out of curiosity - what other vars did you keep in there?